# NGINX: multiple proxy pass for same domain but different ports

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, networking, localhost

Here's the situation:

I have up to 500 independent localhost applications all running simultaneously on a server. My router has ports 80, 443, 8000 to 8500 open. My clients can connect to each of the different localhost applications of their choice. My task is to figure out a way to do this, using 1 domain: example.com

It would be nice if I could use a query string to tell NGINX which application to redirect to. For example, if example.com is my domain name, and I have port 443 open to connect to it, it would be nice if I could do something like:

https://example.com?port=8300

then NGINX will redirect this request to localhost:8300

if this cannot be done, another solution could be to request:
https://example.com:8300

and then NGINX will redirect this request to localhost:8300

my current setup has https://example.com on port 443 redirecting to localhost:8080(the NGINX config code:)

> server {
>
> ```
>     server_name example.com;
>
>     location / {
>             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
>     }
>
> listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
> listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
> ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by
> ```
>
> Certbot
>       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by
>   Certbot
>       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
>       ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
>
> } server {
>       if ($host = example.com) {
>           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
>       } # managed by Certbot
>
> ```
>     listen 80;
>     listen [::]:80;
>
>     server_name example.com;
> return 404; # managed by Certbot
> ```
>
> }

but I need a range of proxy_pass arguments, and they need to correspond to either a query string or a domain name's port.

I found no documentation or online articles on how to do this. Thanks!